# how to open jsfiddle with a previous saved version by default

Tags: jsfiddle

I created a version of my typical daily environment I'm working on (jquery + angular + some personal .js) and I would like to find myself on that base version each time I open jsfiddle.com, instead of finding myself on a blank draft that forces me to go to the dashboard, open the version I would like to work with and fork it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not possible, I'd just add your base to bookmarks and use it instead